# How would I parse this json?

Tags: php, json

I've been having issues trying to parse this json data.
I tried to do this to return the name but its not working:

```
 foreach(json_decode($test) as $item){  
 $name= $item->users->name;}
```

This is the json code:

```
 {
  "users":[
 {
 "id":"dsfdfsd",
 "id_str":"dsfsdf",
 "name":"Davy",
 "screen_name":"Davy232",
 "location":"Colorado"
 },
{
 "id":"wer",
 "id_str":"wer",
 "name":"Sarah",
 "screen_name":"Davy232",
 "location":"LA"
  },
 {
 "id":"fdf",
 "id_str":"fdf",
 "name":"James",
 "screen_name":"James374",
 "location":"Vegas"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the JSON is invalid , Here's the proper fixed JSON

#### Fixed JSON Data

```
{
   "users":[
  {
     "id":"dsfdfsd",
     "id_str":"dsfsdf",
     "name":"Davy",
     "screen_name":"Davy232",
     "location":"Colorado"
  }
]
}
```

What were the problems ?

- You did not surround `dsfdfsd` with doubles quotes.
- There was an extra comma after *Colorado*
- The braces were not properly balanced.

Also, your `foreach` should be like this..

```
foreach(json_decode($test) as $item){  
 echo $item[0]->name;
 }
```

<kbd>[Working Demo - Part 1](https://eval.in/138689)</kbd>
<kbd>[Working Demo - Part 2](https://eval.in/138690)</kbd>

Comment: sorry that was a quick copy and paste of the beggining part of the JSON data that was returned to me... The JSON data i have is correct

Comment: is their something i have to do different because of the bracket after users?

Comment: Yes the square brackets `[` indicates an array .. that's why I had used  it as such inside the `foreach` construct. Did you check the demo ?

Comment: Thanks that sorta worked... I changed my code up above to show more users. using  $item[0]->name; only displays the first user over again

Comment: @user2423476, The JSON shows invalid to me. Can you paste the right one ?

Comment: should be fixed now forgot a comma